# Put Background Data in UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 3 dynamic Cells.

Cell A
Cell B
Cell C

While clicking a Cell, a new View will be opened with a Segue. I commit the Text "Cell A" (...) to the other View. But I need other Data to proceed (for example an unique ID). How can I transfer this without the user can see?

Comment: You can send whatever data you wish in prepareForSegue method, which is called right before new View is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1) Create a variable yourUniqueId in your destination view controller.

2) Add following method in your root view controller.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "YourSegue"
    {
        let tempController = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
        tempController.yourUniqueId = "UNIQUEID"

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to know, how I can save a unique id next to the cell text. The Cell text is visible and the ID should be in Background

Comment: You can add a label and hide it so that it is not visible to the user. But this is not the right way of doing it. Instead store all the unique ids in an array with its index corresponding to the cell row and pass it to the destination View in prepareForSegue.

Comment: My Problem is that I can have more Cells with the Same Name... "A", "B", "C", "A"